# exception in deploying simple richfaces application

Tags: jsf, glassfish, richfaces

i am getting the following exception when deploying a simple richfaces application
i am using glassfish 3.1.1 and have all the necessary jars in my classpath.
Though the applicatioin deploys i can't figure out why this exception pops up.

i have the following jars:

```
richfaces-core-api-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.2.2.Final-sources.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.2.2.Final-sources.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.2.2.Final-sources.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.2.2.Final-sources.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-archetype-kitchensink.jar
richfaces-archetype-simpleapp.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
guava-13.0.1.jar
guava-gwt-13.0.1.jar
sac-1.3.jar
```

The following is the exception:

```
    SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.richfaces.application.ServiceTracker.release(ServiceTracker.java:132)
        at
org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.onStop(InitializationListener.java:137)
        at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.processEvent(InitializationListener.java:149)
        at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2168)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2144)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:302)
        at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:683)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStop(StandardContext.java:4840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5584)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:527)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1049)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2229)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2184)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.stop(WebApplication.java:159)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.stop(EngineRef.java:169)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.stop(ModuleInfo.java:302)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.stop(ApplicationInfo.java:329)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.unload(ApplicationLifecycle.java:998)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.undeploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1024)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.UndeployCommand.execute(UndeployCommand.java:330)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:353)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.handleRedeploy(DeployCommand.java:607)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:274)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:353)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:126)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

want to know exactly what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

it seems something is wrong with the mojarra reference implementation that comes with glassfish. Try reinstalling glassfish. It happens to me all the time...